# Define a class (instance)method in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods

Is there any way to define a method for a class instance in the console?

e.g.

```
 def Model.old?
   self.created_at < Time.now - 35.years
 end
```

And then run it with

```
Model.find(1).old?
```

Comment: Should be able to open a class like normal.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I want to define a method that I'm testing without going into the class, reloading or (importantly) losing the bit of data I've been fiddling with. But I want to define the method to behave as if it was already defined against the model.

Comment: Opening a class doesn't reload the class, AFAIK. You're trying to add an instance method, not to a specific instance, and I don't see any reason you couldn't do that. Are you saying using normal Ruby class opening isn't working?

Comment: Well, what I just wrote above didn't work....

Comment: Well, no, I think that'd add a class method if anything. You'd want `class Model; def old?; (your code); end; end` or something. E.g., http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html or any of a bunch of other tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, this should be what you want:

```
class Model
  def old?
    created_at < 35.years.ago
  end
end
```

You just need to enter each line into the console one by one.

P.S. - Your comparison logic is backwards, so I flipped it back around.